# android CountDownTimer - last onTick not called - what clean solution to use?

Tags: android, timer, countdown

frustration post ....

I just stumbled into the "CountDownTimer - last onTick not called" problem many have reported here.

Simple demo showing the problem

```
package com.example.gosh;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;

public class CountDownTimerSucksActivity extends Activity {

int iDontWantThis = 0; // choose 100 and it works yet ...

private static final String TAG = "CountDownTimerSucksActivity";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    new MyCountDownTimer(10000 + iDontWantThis , 1000).start();
}

class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    long startSec;

    public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        startSec = System.currentTimeMillis() ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e(TAG, " onFinish (" + getSeconds() + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e(TAG, millisUntilFinished + " millisUntilFinished" + " (" + getSeconds() + ")");

    }

    protected long getSeconds() {
        return  (((System.currentTimeMillis() - startSec) / 1000) % 60);

    }

}

}
```

The logcat output from a test run ...

[image: logcat ouput]

As you can see the last call onTick is happening with 1963ms millisUntilFinished, then the next call is onFinished nearly 2 seconds later. Surely a buggy behavior. I found many posts on this yet no clean solution yet. One I included in the source code, if you set the iDontWantThis field to 100 it works.

I dont mind workarounds in minor fields yet this seems such a core functionality that i cant fathom it wasnt fixed yet. What are you people doing to have a clean solution for this?

Thanks a lot

martin

**UPDATE:**

A very useful modification of the CountDownTimer by Sam which does not surpresses the last tick due to internal ms delay and also prevents the accumulation of ms delay with each tick over time can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762272/android-countdowntimer-additional-milliseconds-delay-between-ticks)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Countdown timer starts from a second after it is supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783313/countdown-timer-starts-from-a-second-after-it-is-supposed-to)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior you are experiencing is actually explicitly defined in the `CountdownTimer` code; [have a look at the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java).

Notice inside of `handleMessage()`, if the time remaining is less than the interval, it explicitly does not call `onTick()` and just delays until complete.

Notice, though, from the source that `CountdownTimer` is just a very thin wrapper on `Handler`, which is the real timing component of the Android framework.  As a workaround, you could very easily create your own timer from this source (less than 150 lines) and remove this restriction to get your final tick callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot, quite new to android and I havent made the step to actually look into its source code in cases like that. Thanks a lot for pointing me to that step. I will implement my own CountDownTimer as suggested which always calls onTick if millisUntilFinished > 0 and i can check easily if the remaining millis allow for what i want to do (actually i just need countdown timer which displays 6,5,4,3,2,1,0 )

Comment: just for the sake of completeness, removing the following else if block does the job to have onTick called whenever there are millis left ----------------------------------------------------------------      } else if (millisLeft < mCountdownInterval) {
                    // no tick, just delay until done
                    sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), millisLeft);
                }

Answer (score 2):

I think the frustration comes from an incorrect expectation of what a tick should be. As the other answer noted, this behavior is intentional. Another possible way of handling this is to simply specify a smaller interval. If you were implementing some sort of countdown clock for example, it wouldn't hurt to change the interval to 500. If it's important that some work is only done when the seconds change, then you can do that too by storing the result of `getSeconds()` and only doing that work when that value changes.

If `CountdownTimer` were changed to always fire that last tick even if the remaining time is less than the interval, I'm sure StackOverflow would have a bunch of questions like "why do I not have enough time in the last tick of `CountdownTimer`?"

Comment: You are right I just expected different behaviour which is the source of the frustration. I am surprised the intended behaviour it is not mentioned in the API docu, particular as in the logcat above it can be seen the countdown timer it is actually "late" with every tick as it fires 47 ms later than the given secondsLeft/intervals and that very 47ms causes that onTick is not called as I was expecting it. Just imagine the case you give 4 hours as intervall, who would expect onTick not to be called because of 43ms. But yes that is the problem with expectations ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you say that it is intentional behaviour, the API says exactly:

"Schedule a countdown until a time in the future, with regular notifications on intervals along the way."

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }
}.start();
```

if you set the time to 30 seconds, and the countDownInterval to 1000, as the API says regular, it should be fired exactly 30 times.
I think it's not an intentional behaviour but a wrong implementation.

The solution should be the one proposed by Sam here:

[android CountDownTimer - additional milliseconds delay between ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762272/android-countdowntimer-additional-milliseconds-delay-between-ticks)

Comment: Thanks Juan - Sam's solution is already referred to in the update of the post.

Answer (score 1):

Android's [CountDownTimer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java) calls **onTick()** for the first time as soon as (without delay) the timer is started (as can be seen on [line number 93](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java#93))

Post this, onTick() is called based upon the time remaining until the timer is completed.

> If the time remaining until timer completed is less than the time interval specified, then onTick() is not called ([line number 136](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java#136)). This is the reason your last onTick() is not being called.

### Modified CountDownTimer class

I have modified the timer to call onTick() all intervals (including first and last) after specified delay. Here is the class -

```java
public abstract class CountDownTimer {

    private final long mMillisInFuture;
    private final long mCountdownInterval;
    private long mStopTimeInFuture;

    private boolean mCancelled = false;

    public CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        mMillisInFuture = millisInFuture;
        mCountdownInterval = countDownInterval;
    }

    public synchronized final void cancel() {
        mCancelled = true;
        mHandler.removeMessages(MSG);
    }

    public synchronized final CountDownTimer start() {
        mCancelled = false;
        if (mMillisInFuture <= 0) {
            onFinish();
            return this;
        }
        mStopTimeInFuture = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mMillisInFuture;
        onTick(mMillisInFuture);
        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG), mCountdownInterval);
        return this;
    }

    public abstract void onTick(long millisUntilFinished);

    public abstract void onFinish();

    private static final int MSG = 1;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            synchronized (CountDownTimer.this) {
                if (mCancelled)
                    return;
                final long millisLeft = mStopTimeInFuture - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                if (millisLeft <= 0) {
                    onFinish();
                } else {
                    onTick(millisLeft);
                    sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), mCountdownInterval);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```