# Need a CountdownTimer that is Accurate and can be Paused android

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer that counts down from 60 to 0 seconds.  I've been having fun (not!) trying to get CountDownTimer to work with a pause and be accurate as far as the Timing.

[android CountDownTimer - additional milliseconds delay between ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762272/android-countdowntimer-additional-milliseconds-delay-between-ticks/12762416#12762416)

The above link fixes the inaccuracies somewhat, but display sometimes starts at 60 seconds and sometimes at 59 seconds.

In addition, I need to be able to pause the timer.  I tried using this implementation for pause, but this implementation was based on Android's CountDownTimer and has the inaccuracies discussed in the first link:

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Timer/multitimer-android/com/cycleindex/multitimer/CountDownTimerWithPause.java.htm

Anyone have any ideas on how to implement a CountDownTimer with pause that is accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at the answer from Sam [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762272/android-countdowntimer-additional-milliseconds-delay-between-ticks), is the most accurate I've found!