# Kotlin - press a button 1 time, show messages several times in TextView

Tags: loops, kotlin, textview, delay

How to implement showing several messages in a TextView field one by one with a required delay by clicking button only one time?

I tried this (look at the code below) and got such a result:
three seconds go by and only "3" is shown in the end. Digits 1 and 2 aren't shown.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.button.setOnClickListener {test()}
}

fun test() {
    for (i in (1..3)){
        binding.text1.text = "${i}"
        Thread.sleep(1000L)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You **really shouldn't sleep Main Thread**. Main thread is used to display UI by sleeping it you are blocking the whole UI and that is why it is not updating. You can use **[Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)** to run code every second

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //your method
  }
}, 0, 1000);//1 second
```

So for example you can start timer on button click and stop it after 3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip about Timer.

This thread helped me further.
[How to create a simple countdown timer in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095875/how-to-create-a-simple-countdown-timer-in-kotlin)

Now my code looks like this and it works and does what I wanted:

```
fun test() {
    var cnt = 3
    val timer = object: CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            binding.text1.text = cnt.toString()
            cnt--
        }
        override fun onFinish() {
            binding.text1.text = "That's it"
        }
    }
    timer.start()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sleeping the main thread isn't solution for such simple task you should use concurrency like the code below using corouties

```
suspend fun test(){
     for(i in (1..3) {
         delay(1000L)
         binding.text1.text = i.toStrong()
     }
}
```

And `invokeOnCompletion {}` is pretty good callback to handle completion

Comment: Suspend function 'test' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function