# Click on a button 5 times in 3 seconds in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I wanted to move another activity by clicking a button 5 times in 3 seconds in Kotlin. I know I can use the following code:

```js
var click = 0

button.setOnClickListener {
  click++
  if (click == 5) {
    val intent = Intent(activity, SecretRoom::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
  } else {

  }
}
```

But how can I reset the click to 0 again after 3 seconds has passed after the first click?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use a Coroutines, read this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html

Comment: Can you please give an example on how to use the Coroutines for the above case? Thanks.

Comment: Sure! Super busy today but I'll try later

Comment: Why not use a simple countdown timer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095875/how-to-create-a-simple-countdown-timer-in-kotlin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58448610/14120486 this answer uses coroutines also! Give it a look @Tommy

Comment: Hi @Cloverleaf , can you please give a code example by using countdown timer? kinda new to this, thanks!

Comment: @ItzDavi alright, can I see the code example for the above case by using coroutine? only 2 minutes?

Comment: @Tommy Here an example, step by step: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/countdowntimer-in-android-using-kotlin/

Comment: @Tommy you can adjust the timer delay

Comment: @Cloverleaf Thanks a lot mate, I have applied your suggestion.