# Countdown Timer in Compose/Kotlin Multiplatform (without CountDownTimer)

Tags: kotlin, timer, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

What is the best and easiest way to create a countdown timer (lets say it starts at 3 minutes), which can be started, paused, stopped and reset? I'm creating a Compose/Kotlin Multiplatform project, so CountDownTimer is not an option, since it's from Android and I dont want to use expect/actual here. [Kotlins timer function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/timer.html) would work, but I cant find any examples that use it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a simple countdown timer in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58448610/6216216)

Comment: @Leviathan i solved it in a similar manner, yes thank you